# SQL Server application blank screen

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Does anyone come across this issue? All of as sudden over the weekend, my SQL Server application shows up all blank. This only happen to my SQL Server and none of my other application. I didn't do any special update or changes in windows configurations.

[image]

[SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YVT6.png)

Comment: What is "SQL Server Application" Is that SSMS?

Comment: I'm guessing... new antivirus update.

Comment: Tried reinstalling?

Comment: @TheGameiswar the user posted a screenshot of ssms. The issue is that it's blank...

Comment: What happens if you expand the "Databases" node?

Comment: Yes I'm refering to SSMS

Comment: I did uninstall it and try to install again. The icon shows up on my task bar but the application window never shows up and I can't do anything with it.